# how to import a class from a .py file in another folder

Tags: python, path

I have searched related questions and tested many solutions there, for example,
I found [a solution here]:https://askubuntu.com/a/470989/608783, but I found it does not work in my case...

I have the following file structure:

```
Folder1
  Folder2
     __init__.py
     model.py
  Folder3
     __init__.py
     test.py
```

In `model.py` I defined a class:`class mymodel()`, then in `test.py` I wanna to use `mymodel`, so I tried `from ..Folder2 import mymodel`, `from ..Folder2.model import mymodel`, but all failed with error `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

What should I do? Thanks for any advice.

**Edit**: I am very sorry for not list out `_init_.py` files, they are indeed included in the Folder2 and Folder3. However, the content of them are different from which proposed by @anekix's solution. 
The following are from my possibly wrong setting:

- `__init__.py` in Folder2: `from .model import mymodel`
- `__init__.py` in Folder3: empty

What is wrong with my two `__init__.py`, thank you again.

**Update**: One way to solve this problem is by set all `__init__.py` to empty and then follow @jeffy proposed solution. Another way is by @anekix proposed solution, which should also works for this kind of problem(you should have a try) although not in my case, possibly because the whole project of mine is too messy.

Comment: As stated in the accepted answer you link to, *you also need a __init__.py in all your folders.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python)

Comment: your `__init__.py` file seems correct.and in which folder are you making imports .main.py(assuming here you are making imports) file should be in `folder3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could work:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/Folder1")
from Folder2.model import classname
```

Comment: yeah but it is not the proper way when dealing with subfolders

Comment: Should i set `_init_.py` in Folder2 and Folder3 empty?

Comment: Yes, you can leave `__init__.py` empty in this example.

Comment: @NasefKhan this is the worst way of doing this thing!

Comment: If i add this to `test.py`, set `__init__.py` both to empty and then run it as before(i.e., run `test.py` from Folder3), i met a new error `ImportError: cannot import name mymodel`

Comment: Update: after modifying several import relations. Now it works. Thanks for @Jelly and all persons here.

Comment: @anekix, Sorry if I am coming across as as overly critical or negative, but this solution works for me. I got an `ImportError` using your solution.

Answer (score 1):

you should make both subfolders as a package(by creating `__init__.py` in both subfolders) for proper management and imports:

structure should be:

```
Folder1
  Folder2
     __init__.py
     model.py
  Folder3
     __init__.py
     test.py
```

inside `folder2/__init__.py` add this code below:

```
from model import *
# it imports everything defined in model.py so that
# you can access classes or functions from this python file
```

inside `folder3/__init__.py` folder3  add this code below:

```
from test import *
# it imports everything defined in test.py
```

Then from inside `folder3` you can use the import as(assuming you have some file main.py in `folder3`) :

```
from folder2 import someClass 
# someClass is a class defined in `model.py`
```

So steps are:

```
make `folder2` a package.
make `folder3` a package.
import using `folder1.someClass` or `folder2.someClass`.
```

Comment: Running test.py gives: ImportError: No module named Folder2

Comment: why do you import folder2 in test.py or why do you run `test.py`? the code that you want to run should be in `main.py` or watever name you want(inside `folder3`). then use imports from that `main.py` it will help you structure your code in a better way

Comment: Using your method, I cannot import anything in Folder2 from a script in Folder3. I've tried both "from Folder2 import SomeClass" and "import Folder2.SomeClass". Have you tried running this yourself?

Comment: Thank you @anekix for sincere help. But it gives an error: `ImportError: No module named Folder2`.

Comment: @ytutow Did you create `__init__.py` in `folder2`?can you paste your modified code structure and contenets inside file maybe some sample class so that i can find out why is it giving error for you

Comment: Ok, you can make this method work if you add the full path to `Folder1` to `sys.path` as per Jelly bean's answer. Then do `from Folder2 import SomeClass`.

Comment: @anekix, yes, I followed your proposed solution and current file structure are listed in edited post.

Comment: @ytutow what did you write in `__init__.py` file?make sure its `double underscore` . you should use `__init__.py` not `_init_.py`

Comment: @anekix, in `_init_.py` in Folder2, it is `from model import *`, while for the other  folder it is `from test import *`, i guess i followed your instructions.

Comment: @ytutow it should be `__init__.py` with double undescores what you have written is `_init_.py` just single underscore and that is why you are getting error

Comment: yes, although here I made several typo regrading this (I am sorry), their name are correctly named as `__init__.py`. I mean they are indeed correctly named locally although here I made this typo mistake.